# Test if a player has drank a water bottle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a minigame with a water system.
Is there a command to test if a player has drunk a water bottle, and activate a command off of that?

Comment: I had no idea what to try, I'm not so good with commands. -_-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First run this command once:

```
/scoreboard objectives add HasDrunk stat.useItem.minecraft.potion
```

This makes a scoreboard value that will increase by one for anyone who drinks a potion (which, by the game code, includes water bottles).

Next, in a repeating command block set to always active (number one in the below picture), write whatever command you want to activate, using `@a[score_HasDrunk_min=1]` instead of the player's name. Run another command if you want from the number 2 command block. Add as many as necessary all facing the same direction. Finally, in the last command block, write:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_HasDrunk_min=1] HasDrunk 0
```

**Disclaimer:**

You cannot use this with conjunction with drinkable potions. As a workaround, you could only give people splash potions

Comment: command one raises error Usage: Invalid Object Criteria Type

Comment: @hyperviper11 Whoops, I misread the wiki. Instead of `potion`, it's `minecraft.potion`.

Answer (score 3):

Since this has already been answered, I want to help update those who are looking at this from 2017+.

`stat.useItem.minecraft` has since 1.13 become `minecraft.used:minecraft`.